# R: group_by does not group when using own function

Tags: r

I have been working with `magrittr` and `dplyr` for a while now and like the pipelines. However, in my current script the group_by funtion does not seem to group when I use it for my own functions:

The dataframe looks something like this, only larger:

```
df <- data.frame(Participant = c(rep("A",10), rep("B", 10)), Speech = c(1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0))
```

I have several functions that I need in order to clean these data and I found that most of my functions do not group by participant, but uses the entire dataframe. One of these functions is the following:

```
segment_finder <- function(kolin){
  kolom <- kolin %>% pull(Speech)
  part <- kolin %>% pull(Participant) %>% as.character() %>% first()
  vorige <- NA
  leng <- 0
  out <- data.frame(segment = numeric(), lengte = numeric())

  for (m in kolom){  
    if(is.na(vorige)){
      vorige <- m
      leng %<>% +1
    }
    else if(m != vorige) {  
      out %<>% bind_rows(data.frame(segment = vorige, lengte = leng))
      leng <- 1
      vorige <- m
    }
    else {      
      leng %<>% + 1
    }
  }
  out %<>% bind_rows(data.frame(segment = m, lengte = leng))
  out %<>% mutate(Participant = part)
  return(out)
}
```

Using the following code does work, so I found a way around it, but it keeps bugging me that the pipeline does not. I have tried loading dplyr last, but that does not work.

```
df3 <- df %>% plyr::ddply("Participant", segment_finder)
```

Comment: that's probably an issue with non-standard evaluation. This site might help you: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html

Comment: but also - please if you ask questions, make your code reproducible. If you are using custom functions, this also includes sharing the code for the functions.

Comment: additionally, show non-base packages. You are using `dplyr` here, not (just) `magrittr`. You might be able to do `%>% do(thresholder(.,j,i)) %>% bind_rows() ...`, not certain without knowing what's going on in your functions.

Comment: This isn't necessarily about non-standard evaluation, it's because the `dlpyr` verb functions know about grouped data, but nothing else does. The only difference between (e.g.) `mtcars` and `group_by(mtcars,cyl)` is that the latter has an attribute listing which rows are in which groups. If your function does not look for and *use* that attribute, then your function is ignoring the grouping. Take a look at `str(group_by(mtcars,cyl))` to see what is stored there and perhaps how you can take advantage of it.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I have edited the question so that the code is reproducible.

Comment: I have edited the question, but am unable to figure out myself what causes the problem and how to solve it. @r2evans, could you perhaps help me?

Comment: Now your example does not include `group_by`. In general, I suggest you use `dplyr` or `plyr`, not both. That doesn't mean that it cannot happen, but there are enough conflicts and such that I gave up and stuck with the former. Again, if you want to use `group_by` and a custom function, then your function needs to *actively* look for groups. Perhaps within your function you can use `group_rows(kolin)` that returns a list where each element is a group of row indices.